# Initializing data using nuxtjs asyncData hook slows page rendering

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js

Loading data from within the `asyncData` hook using `$axios` causes a slight delay when loading the page. I want a natural and fast page movement like when loading data using mounted hook, but I can't use `mounted` because of SEO.
Is there any solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the non blocking [`fetch()` hook](https://nuxtjs.org/docs/features/data-fetching#the-fetch-hook), seems like the perfect solution in your case.